# chrome.tabCapture is undefined when extension icon is clicked

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use the chrome extension [tabCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabCapture/) API. To do this, I hooked up a simple background script that adds a click handler to the extension icon (via `chrome.action`). The handler should start capturing the tab via a simple call to `chrome.tabCapture.capture`. However, `tabCapture` is undefined. The full source consists of two files. The contents are shown below.

manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "tab capture test",
    "description": "Manifest v3 tab capture test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions":[
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "tabCapture",
        "scripting"   
    ],
    "action": {}
}
```

background.js

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.tabCapture.capture(
        {
            video: true,
        },
        (stream) => {
            console.log(stream)
        }
    )
})
```

This results in an error when I click the extension icon.
`Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'capture')`

Why might `tabCapture` be undefined?

Comment: ManifestV3 is still half-implemented, half-broken. See https://crbug.com/1214847.

Answer (score 7):

Update 2023-12

now, you can use `offscreen` API

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/offscreen

How to use:

Video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTLSoM12jlE

Code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RIMAXkWguNkZiDXesmTi0RqHVG1mFuF3/view

---

Manifest v3 has a problem

Manifest v2 has no problem

Hope to solve this problem by 2023.

---

Details:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1214847

Answer (score 0):

i am having the same problem. The problem is that in manifest version 3 this feature only works in popup. If you use version 2, it will work without any problems.